# passing arguments to java program using ANT

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant, classpath

my question is really simple, since this is the first time I use ANT for java, and I don't have much experience in xml ( almost 0% experience ), I need to know some things... I already know basic things like specifying a target with a name and a dependency, and I tried running a java program by typing ant in the command prompt and it worked with no problems at all....my question is:

how do I pass an argument to ant without typing "-Dsomething", since that's what everything online is telling me... I need to type an argument as simple as "-p" or "-e" and I want to tell ant to pass these arguments over to the java program when I run it.. When I type something like:

```
<target name="-e" depends="compile">
    <java classname="MainClass">
        <arg value="-e"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

and in cmd I type : ant -e , I get help options.. as it appears that -e is predefined for ant... can I override ant arguments or something?? please I'm very new to ant and I really need help... though I'm a java expert :/

Comment: If you want to pass "-e" to your java, why would you type it as part of your cmd to call ant? <arg value...> as you put it here should pass "-e" directly to your java. Are you trying to pass this still or something like "-e <othervalue>"?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I pass an argument to ant without typing "-Dsomething"

You don't.

Arguments to Ant starting with a dash are treated as switches to ant itself, arguments without a dash are the names of targets to execute. If you want to pass data from the command line into an `<arg>` of a `java` task then the only way to do it is using properties.

You could always write your own she'll script or batch file that accepts options like `-e` and calls ant with the appropriate `-D` property definitions.